# MediaElement: PosterSource, where are you?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I am using `MediaElement` in my program.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="MyVideo.mp4" Height="480" Width="640" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill" />
```

In various articles I see the possibility of using the `PosterSource` property in this element.

```
<MediaElement PosterSource="imageUri" />
```

This property is missing in my media. Where could there be a mistake?

P.S. I use Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. The version of .NET Framework is 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is available only in UWP applications.